# Text in html/css won't move to the left

Tags: html, css, text, centering

so I was beginning work on an html/css document and can't find out exactly why the text isn't positioned correctly in my menu bar. I've tried to put the text align: left; and margin: 0 auto and padding: 0 and none of these seem to work. I've also looked through a good amount of the questions and run my html/css through validator.w3.org. If anyone is able to help me out that would be great!

HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>title!</title>
    <link href="css/styles.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

    <body>
    <div id="site_title">
        <h2><span>the problem</span></h2>
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a href="is.html">is </a></li>|
        <li><a href="that.html">that </a></li>|
        <li><a href="my.html">my </a></li>|
        <li><a href="text.html">text </a></li>|
        <li><a href="isn'tcentered.html">isn't centered</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

css:

```
body
{
font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", "Avant-Garde";
font-size: 14px;
color:black;
text-align: left;
background-image: white;
margin: 50px 40px 20px 100px ;
}

div#site_title  
{
font-size: 21px;
letter-spacing: 1.5px;
}

div#menu ul a
{
color:gray;
font-size: 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

div#menu ul a:hover
{
color:black;
}

div#menu li
{
display: inline;
}
```

[j fiddle so you can see!](http://jsfiddle.net/dannav147/XaQbr/5/)

EDIT: I should explain that the menu with the smaller text is the one I want to move a few spaces to the left so it doesn't look tabbed. I also fixed the title so it shows what the actual problem is.

Comment: You want to center div#menu, div#site_title or both?

Comment: Have you tried `text-align: center` in the body or the divs that you want to center?

Comment: The `|` outside the `li` is not allowed.

Comment: @Joe , I forgot to explain I needed to move it to the left so it lines up with the larger text. Sorry about that!

Comment: @Andy , I should have said that I needed to move div#menu to the left, not center it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal of a reset stylesheet is to reduce browser inconsistencies in things like default line heights, margins and font sizes of headings, and so on.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

or

import

- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/
- http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! Is this something I should be using in every document or should I only use it in instances where I can't figure out what my problem is? I just want to make sure I am not developing bad habits of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set fixed width to your containers, so they are 100% width, you have set for `display: inline` for `<li>`, so you can simply center it using `text-align:center` to `<ul>`.

btw. as @putvande said in comment, you can't directly inside `<ul>` you can put only `<li>`. To avoid putting `|`, use this css:

```
div#menu li:after {
    content:'|';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried add this?

```
div#menu ul {
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XaQbr/6/

remove the margin on the body and padding on the ul to see it better centered http://jsfiddle.net/XaQbr/8/

Also the pipes outside of the li's, those are invalid

Answer (score 0):

try this:
div#menu ul{padding:0;}

right-click the element in your browser and click "inspect element". there you can see dimension, margins and paddings in color. (for chrome at least...)

Answer (score 0):

Your markup is invalid. You cannot have the | or any other tags or content in between the li. The separator should be done using border-left or right. You can control height of the separator using line height on the li and spacing using left/right padding on the a not using space.

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="is.html">is</a></li>
    <li><a href="that.html">that</a></li>
    <li><a href="my.html">my</a></li>
    <li><a href="text.html">text</a></li>
    <li><a href="isn'tcentered.html">now centered</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#menu ul a
{
    color:gray;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-decoration: none;    
    padding:0 10px;
}

div#menu ul a:hover
{
    color:black;
}

div#menu li
{
    display: inline;    
    line-height:14px;
    border-left:1px solid gray;
}

div#menu li:first-child{
     border-left:none;   

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XaQbr/10/